# How can I put all pdfs in a folder into my html page as links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pdf

This question has been asked here before but I am still having trouble. I have a small html page and I'd like all the pdfs in a folder in the same directory as my code to be automatically generated as links. So the pdfs are all in a folder called thepdfs which is in the same directory as code.html Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var folder = "thepdfs/";
            $.ajax({
                url: folder,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if (val.match(/\.pdf$/)) { 
                            $("body").append( "<a href='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
                        } 
                   });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="">Hi</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have gone in and created alerts to show where the program is running until. Seems to go right up until `$.ajax`. The site isn't live, I'm just playing around with jQuery and HTML. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how AJAX works. You cannot just call a folder and get a listing of the files in there - that would be *massively* unsecure if it were possible. Instead you need to call some server side code which looks through that folder and tells you what's available in that folder. Note though that file-based systems are intrinsically slow and do not scale well. I would look at moving to a database system if you expect to have more than a couple of concurrent users.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! I'll look into doing through php or something like that instead.